# How to stop Sublime Text 2 from removing the "Read & Execute" flag upon save

Tags: linux, sublimetext2, file-permissions, samba

Using Sublime Text 2, I sometimes have to edit shell files that are executed by bash in a cron. However, when I save these files, the execute flag is being removed from the file, causing the cron to fail when trying to execute the file. I have to chmod the file every time I change it. Previously, using Ultra-Edit, I never had this issue.

Has anyone else dealt with this issue who can recommend a fix or solution?

Comment: Sorry if the question sounds stupid, but could this be a umask rather than a Sublime Text issue? Just to rule out the obvious.

Comment: I don't think so. The file already has the execute permission, it's just being opened, edited, and saved. The only thing I can think of is that Sublime Text, when opening a file, creates a temp file that you are working on locally, and when you save the file, it removes the original from the file system and places the newly saved file in it's place. That would set the file to defaults flags.

Comment: You could try _strace_ and see what happens. (I am nowhere near a PC and cannot replicate this, only provide ideas for self-help.)

Comment: Tried under ubuntu with the latest Sublime Text 2 eding a bash file, I didn't get this problem.

Comment: what OS is that? Ubuntu/OS X?

Comment: I'm running Sublime Text in Windows. The files being modified are done so through a Samba share to a Unix file system.

Comment: Same happens for me with Sublime/Windows/Samba. Never had this problem on OSX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem can be fixed by disabling the [`map_archive`](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#MAPARCHIVE) feature of samba.

```
[global]
map archive = no
```

This should solve the problem.

[Source](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7969)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are editing files through Samba, Sublime Text seems to recreate the file every time it saves it, with the default umask, and not preserve the old permissions.

The workaround to get +x permissions is to set

```
create mask = 755
```

in your Samba's smb.conf file in the relevant share section.

The downside, every new file will have +x now.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't possible in our environment. It sounds like I will be submitting a bug to Sublime Text.